# loop and grab href links info

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
 <p class="page" id="datapage">
 <strong>1</strong> 
 <a class="pag-curr" href="blahblah;page_num=2">
 2
 </a> 
 <a class="pag-curr" href="blahblah;page_num=3">
 3
 </a> 
 ...
 till page number 10
 <a class="pag-next" href="blahblah;page_num=2">
 <strong>next&nbsp;»</strong>
 </a>
 </p>
```

I want to loop the href class="pag-curr" to get the number of counts and want to get their relative href info (eg.blahblah;page_num=2.. etc), how can I achieve it with javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".pag-curr").each(function(){
   var hrf = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can do that with selectors:

```
// Retrieve all links with class pag-curr
var links = $("a.pag-curr");

// Count links
console.log(links.length);

// Print all href attributes
links.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
}
```